# Ошибка в работе Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net

Генерирую ссылку:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home")
```

Получаю на выходе `/`.
А вот если впишу *несуществующие* контроллеры и методы, то делает нормальную ссылку.
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Url.Action()` не проверяет контроллер и экшн на существование. Он ограничивается поиском подходящего роута и сокращением полученной ссылки на основании строк из defaults - у вас это `controller="Home"`, `action="Index"`.

Даже если вы удалите `HomeController` или `HomeController.Index`, `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")` будет все так же выдавать `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Home/Index прописан в RouteConfig как "по умолчанию"

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

и этот путь отображается как корневой.